# How to load remote environment variable in Jupyter notebbok?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am loading a remote kernel in a local Jupyter notebook with the [rk python package](https://github.com/korniichuk/rk). It works fine except no environment variables of the remote are loaded. The question is then:

How to load the remote environment variables when using a remote kernel? Is there something in the asociated kernel.json to modify?